# Determine Marginal Probability density function of X

Tags: statistics

Random Variables X and Y have the joint probability density function
f(x,y)= 8xy/81 for 0 < x < 3 and 0 < y < x
Determine the marginal probability density function of X.

I am confused if I should be using integration of 0 to X or 0 to 3?
fx(X)=$$\frac{8}{81}$$  $$\int_{0}^{3} xy dy$$

: $$\frac{8X}{81}$$  $$\int_{0}^{3} [y^2] dy$$

$$\frac{8X}{81} (3^2) - (0^2)$$
=$$\frac{8X}{27}$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{8x}{27}$ is not even a density function on $0\lt x\lt 3$: it does not integrate to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture of the triangle on which the given joint density function "lives." This is the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(3,0)$, and $(3,3)$.
'
For the (marginal) density $f_X(x)$ of $X$, we want to "integrate out" $y$. Take any fixed value of $x$ between $0$ and $3$, and draw the vertical line through $(x,0)$. Then $y$ travels from $0$ to $x$. So for $0\lt x\lt 3$ we have
$$f_X(x)=\int_0^x \frac{8xy}{81}\,dy.$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining to draw a picture. This makes much more sense now.

Comment: Despite the fact that I have taught this material for many years, I still always make a sketch. If I don't, I am not fully confident I am doing things correctly.